# How to auto-fill domain or field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, fields-attributes, domains

Is It possible to have a domain on a field that then narrows down the domain selection of the next field.

example: Field_1 would have a domain of- Rock, debris and soil
                  If I choose rock from the list above in the next field I would have a pick list of (rock fall, rock spread and rock flow) instead of having all of the examples listed like I placed below
( rock fall, rock spread, rock flow, debris fall, debris spread, debris flow, soil fall, soil spread, and soil flow)

Comment: no subtypes only updates one field @gm70560

Comment: You can set a separate domain for a field under each new subtype.  I finished my coffee and checked it.  I made subtypes for rock, soil, etc (Field_1) and set a description field to different domains (Field_2).

Comment: so rock soil etc would be a domain. what would be the code or description for subtypes? sorry I am little confused. @gm70560

Comment: I don't want to create a subset of features for this feature class @gm70560

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a few pictures would help.

A subtype field can be set to categorize the main types (rock, soil, debris); This would correlate to Field_1.  Notice the desc field domain is set to rock.
[image: subtypes]

Each subtype can set a domain for the desc field.  The soil subtype has the soil subtype for the desc field.
[image: domain_1]

You will need to make domains for acceptable values for each subtype
[image: all_domains]

When the subtype is set, then the desc field (Field_2) when go to the set domain.
[image: editing_1]
[image: editing_2]

Comment: I agree with above answer from @gm70560 as to likely the best way to do this, but it might be relevant to note, if you've already got an existing field you'd want to use as the sub-type field, you may have to re-think that and create a new field of a numeric field type (could delete existing field and create new one with same name) as, at least the last time I checked, only numeric fields can be subtypes (it stores a numeric value for each type in the database, but you see the sub-type description such as "rock" on your screen).  Just clarifying in case you tried using an existing string field